# How to load/display an image onto a PyQT window?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I came across the following code to create a PyQT window.

```
class PrettyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PrettyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(600,300,1000,600)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Browser')

        self.show()    

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PrettyWidget()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like to insert/embed an image onto this window (say image.jpg with the path known). It should preferably be at the bottom of the window and should not consume the entirety of the window. How can I do that ?

Comment: The image should be as a background or should occupy some space.

Comment: The image should occupy some space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use QLabel to display the image since it has a setPixmap method, as I show below

```
lb = QtGui.QLabel(self)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("{path/of/file}")
height_label = 100
lb.resize(self.width(), height_label)
lb.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(lb.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio))
self.show()
```

Complete code:

```
class PrettyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(1000,600)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Browser')

        self.lb = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("test.png")
        height_of_label = 100
        self.lb.resize(self.width(), height_of_label)
        self.lb.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(self.lb.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio))
        self.show()    

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.lb.resize(self.width(), self.lb.height())
        self.lb.setPixmap(self.lb.pixmap().scaled(self.lb.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio))
        QtGui.QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)


    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PrettyWidget()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Bottom:

```
def initUI(self):
    self.resize(1000,600)
    self.center()
    self.setWindowTitle('Browser')

    self.lb = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("test.png")
    height_of_label = 100
    self.lb.resize(self.width(), height_of_label)
    self.lb.move(0, self.height() -self.lb.height())
    self.lb.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(self.lb.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio))
    self.show()    

def resizeEvent(self, event):
    self.lb.resize(self.width(), self.lb.height())
    self.lb.setPixmap(self.lb.pixmap().scaled(self.lb.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio))
    self.lb.move(0, self.height() -self.lb.height())
    QtGui.QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is a slight issue though - the image does not resize on maximizing the window. Along with that, if I were to place the image on the bottom of the window, what modifications are required ?

Comment: If my answer helps you please do not forget to mark it as correct, please.

Comment: The image now resizes perfectly. But in the code,`lb` first needs to be defined as `lb = QtGui.QLabel()` before `self.lb = QtGui.QLabel(self)`. And if I would like the image to be at the bottom, how should the code be modified ?

Comment: Nopes. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I am thinking of having an image at the top as well as at the bottom and tried to understand the codes and combined some of both the snippets of code but it didn't work out. I guess I have to put more efforts but can you suggest me a way out?

Comment: You must place 2 labels and combine both examples.